# Inserting $User.FirstName into a KB Article?

Tags: knowledge, articles

How do I insert a user's first name into an article?

I know it's `{!$User.FirstName}`, but what's the code necessary to do it?

Is it possible to add apex code into the Standard Editor with Source view?

Comment: You need to more specifically describe your problem and the steps you've tried to solve it.  This is way too broad to answer right now.

Comment: {!$User.FirstName} is the "code"? You just put that into your VF Page and it'll display the User's first name. As @CharlesKoppelman says though this is very broad and not particularly clear.

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me .. he's asking for knowledge articles.  @user10164 how and where are you trying to modify these articles and insert this, through the standard editor ?